# STL iterator wrapper

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, wrapper

I would like to write wrapper for STL iterator.
It should only change behavior of some methods...

I see it like smth like this:

```
template<***>
class custom_iterator : public ***
{
    T & iter;

public:
    custom_iterator(T & iter) : iter(iter) {}

    // for example, behaviour that increments value
    T_val operator * () { return (*iter)+1; } 
};
```

How it can be made for all types of iterators? I mean:

- Input Iterator
- Output Iterator
- Forward Iterator
- Bidirectional Iterator
- Random Access Iterator

How it is possible?

Comment: What's this supposed to achieve? Can't you template your application on the iterator type just like the STL algorithms do? You can then use iterator traits to access specifics of the iterator if needed...

Comment: Its not a question. The OP should first learn to ask questions.

Comment: Nawaz, why it is not a question? I can't find how to make "STL iterator wrapper". Wrapper i mean pattern wrapper, follow interface and delegate calls. What is OP?

Comment: @Nawaz: I have detected at least one question mark in the text, which seems to indicate that it is a question. Probably not the best, as it is missing the problem to solve, but not worse than many other questions in SO...

Comment: @David: Let me rephrase my comment: its not a *meaningful* question. The OP should first learn to ask *meaningful* questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`boost::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html). I think that's what you're trying to get at.

[Source code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp)

Comment: I can't use it because i woul like to change reference type of iterator. But I can follow this source code to make my iterator similar to boost::transform_iterator. Thanks.